# Django: Reverse not found > {% url %} in template

Tags: django, url, arguments, reverse

This problem seems simple and it is described multiple times in SO, but I still can't figure out why it isn't working in my case.

So, I have a url declared in **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<country>[-\w]+)/$', CountryListView.as_view(), name='list_by_country'),)
```

and in my **template** I'm calling the url

```
<a href="{% url 'list_by_country' country.country__name %}" >{{ country.country__name }}</a>
```

However, I am getting the **error message** that the url could not be reversed

```
Reverse for 'list_by_country' with arguments '(u'United Kingdom',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found
```

What is causing the reverse error? Are spaces in the argument maybe not allowed?

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that "United Kingdom" doesn't match the regex `[-\w]+`. If you also want to match spaces, you should change your regex to `[-\w\ ]+`. Example:

```
url(r'^(?P<country>[-\w\ ]+)/$', CountryListView.as_view(), name='list_by_country')
```

You can also choose to match `\s` instead of just a single space character.